# Tmux, disable buffer clear functionality

Tags: terminal, tmux

Is there any possibility to tell Tmux screen to ignore `\033[3J` and not erase the scrollback?

Some commands (react-dev-utils/clearConsole) use `\033[3J` carelessly and I would like to avoid getting my terminal history removed.

I've found [How to stop `clear` from clearing scrollback buffer](https://askubuntu.com/a/812990) and it tells removing `E3=\E[3J` from `infocmp -x $TERM`, but it is not there in the first place.

Comment: Answerers may enjoy issues 7233, 7640, 2495, 611, and a few others at https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot stop tmux doing this when it gets ED 3 without modifying the code.

If the program was getting it from terminfo(5) you could create a modified entry without the E3 capability but it isn't there for `screen` or `tmux` so the program must be sending it without checking if it is supported.